# Android - custom view and animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I am experimenting with Views in Android and am trying to create a custom 'widget'. What I want to do is create a portion of a circle with an indicator at 12'o clock. I'd then like to to swipe over the circle and when I do, I'd like to see the indicator move to left or right corresponding to a swipe to the left or the right.

I have looked up a number of sources however I am unsure of how to draw an 'indicator' within the arc. In addtion, what needs to be done to animate the arc ? Can this be achieved without OpenGL ?

I am aware of the circlular progress bar and I believe the problem is quite similar, however I didn't have to add a marker inside the circle.

Here is an image of the screen shot of the View I would like to recreate:

[image: sample pic]

Comment: use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator` and read **carefully** `Canvas` API

Answer (score 0):

This approach would work,Creating a View with rounded corners and position it to bottom to make it seem like arc [image]